# Split mysql retrieved data into headers and rows

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, html-table

I retrieve data from DB and I need to insert all of them in a table.
I have some constant headers and some that depends on the query results.

Below you can see a table; how i want it to look like:
[image]

I did prepare the HTML structure:

```
<table class="table-fill">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>CODE</th>
    <th colspan=2>TREND A</th>      
    <th colspan=2>TREND B</th>
    <th colspan=2>TREND C</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th>Items</th>
    <th>Revenue</th>
    <th>Items</th>
    <th>Revenue</th>
    <th>Items</th>
    <th>Revenue</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody class="table-hover">
<tr>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>A</td>
   <td>10</td>
   <tD>150</td>
   <td>5</td>
   <tD>200</td>
   <td>8</td>
   <tD>120</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

No problem so far. The hard part is to use actual data from DB and insert them to the table.

Headers "trend a", "trend b" etc are not constants. The below tables will be displayed on different countries. Some countries have specific trend names. Let's say England has "Trend A", "Trend B" and "Trend D". Italy has only "Trend A" etc.

Is it possible to write php code and in some way auto generate the table headers based on the query results?

And then split the results by trend so that correct values will go to correct trend?

I know how to do a simple table like:

```
$sql_r = "SELECT o.id, o.code, tl.name, ts.items, ts.revenue
          FROM overview o, trend_stats ts, trend_lang tl           
                    WHERE o.id_shop = '1'
                    AND o.id = ts.id
                    AND ts.id_trend = tl.id_trend";
$data_to_output = Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS($sql_r);

foreach ($data_to_output as $data) {
    echo '
        <tr>
        <td>'.$data['id'].'</td>
        <td>'.$data['code'].'</td>
        <td>'.$data['trend'].'</td>
        <td>'.$data['items'].'</td>
        <td>'.$data['revenue'].'</td>
        </tr> 
    ';    
}
```

But I'm not sure how to split and structure them the way I want them to be. If there's any tutorial or anything online related to what I'm asking I'm happy to check it out. Thank you

Comment: Where does the trend type information come from? You may need to query the database twice.

Comment: It is information from database. It's a long and complicated query so I decided to use as easy names/variables as possible so users can understand the table and what I want to achieve :)

Comment: Trends belong to a db table. Each trend has an ID and the data below are from another table which is paired to the corresponding trend ID. Also the trends are paired to countries table. Each country has different trends. That;s why I said the headers are not static.

Comment: How you will need to go about constructing/filling the table really depends on what your query results look like and especially how the trend name is identified in the query. Can you add an example of a query output that does not have all of the trends?

Comment: Hello, I added a simple query showing how I retrieve the data. The thing is that query might return trend a,b,c or just trend a,d for example. And based on that results I need to build the table headers and also split the data per those columns. That is the tricky part I do not understand

Comment: Will it have the same number of rows?

Comment: frz3993 the number of rows will be the same yes. In case no items sold on let's say "Trend B" in Code "B" then I will just display '0' or null value.

Comment: Sorry, I still can't imagine how your db schema looks like. But I think it is possible but will require several loops and several calls to the database. For example first call is selecting country and left join the trend. Loop the result to create the header.

Comment: Can you post your table schema and some sample data.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that other than rewrite your headers. The fact that you want to retrieve your informations from your database tells that you'll have to work with any kind of loop. So you first have to display your headers and then display your informations. The only way is to store somewhere in your loop the value that will change your headers when it changes, and add another line of header when the value actually changes. You can do that with just a simple if condition.